# Will my linker link objects from unneeded source files?

Tags: c, linker

When compiling a project, if my source files include a file with no used functions, will the unneeded object file be included in the compiler's output?

e.g.

foo.c

```
int main() {return 0;}
```

bar.c

```
void unusedFunction {;}
```

compiler execution:

```
gcc foo.c bar.c -o output
```

Would the output file be any smaller if I had omitted bar.c from the compiler command?

Comment: Likely, yes. Why do you include files you don't want to use?

Comment: The answer is silly, but I'm trying to write a Makefile for Arduino projects which I wish to compile without using the Arduino IDE. I want all of the Arduino core sources available in case their functions are needed, but it would be nice to not have the unneeded sources in the final code.

Answer (score 4):

Most linkers will link unneeded files unless you tell them not to.  There are flags for this.

Suppose you link with two unnneeded files: an object file and a library:

```
gcc main.o unneeded.o -lunneeded
```

With GNU Binutils or Gold, the flags are `--gc-sections` for unneeded symbols / object files, and `--as-needed` for libraries.  These are linker flags, however, so they must be prefixed with `-Wl,`.  Note that the order of these flags is important—flags only apply to libraries and object files which appear *after* the flags on the command line, so the flags must be specified first.

```
gcc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--gc-sections main.o unneeded.o -lunneeded
```

On OS X, there is a different linker so the flags are different.  The `-dead_strip` flag removes unneeded symbols / object files, and the `-dead_strip_dylibs` flag removes unneeded libraries.

```
gcc -Wl,-dead_strip -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs main.o unneeded.o -luneeded
```

### Example

```
$ cat main.c
int main() { }
$ cat unneeded.c
void unneeded() { }
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gcc -c unneeded.c
```

If we link normally, we get everything...

```
$ gcc main.o unneeded.o -lz
$ nm a.out | grep unneeded
0000000000400574 T unneeded
$ readelf -d a.out | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

With the right flags, we get just what we need...

```
$ gcc -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--gc-sections main.o unneeded.o -lz
$ nm a.out | grep unneeded
$ readelf -d a.out | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Every source or object file referenced in the compilation command will be included in the final executable.

To include only what's needed, build a static library from your objects, and refer to it when linking, rather than to individual objects. Static libraries were invented just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Scons (http://www.scons.org/) or Gradle (http://www.gradle.org/) to figure out the dependencies and will then just link the appropriate bits (assuming you are using static linking)

Dynamic linking is another matter — you get the lot as other programs may need the additional stuff.

But as to the command line given it will link it in. Why add it in the first place if it is not required?

Comment: Some linkers only include a given shared library if it satisfies some undefined symbol at the point in the link where it is scanned; others include the shared library unconditionally.